# Listview using assets Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, assets

I am developing an application which consists of list view,until here every thing is working fine for me, here is my problem,how i can pass the values to list view from assets folder?

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("text.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
```

Comment: what you want ? text.txt is ?

Comment: Do you know how to [Read file from Assets](http://goo.gl/tPI6Z)?

Comment: I have gonr through u r code ,but i am not having the idea how to pass it to list view,in case of textview we will pass it as settext then how we will pass it for listview..

Answer (score 0):

Read the txt file line by line. Extract strings you want, save them in List/ArrayList/strig[] and pass them to the constructor of the adapter. You started good with the opening the file from the assets folder.